# Callbacks on axios-redux-middleware request do not fire

Tags: reactjs, redux, axios, redux-middleware

Can someone explain to me why callbacks defined on action creator do not fire?

The code in question can be seen [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/4k8kkn5mx).

Is this plugin good to work with? (It seems abandoned.)
How should I handle API calls in medium application?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out,i have misunderstand the documentation (not first time).
If you want to use those callbacks in your action, you must pass it with this syntax:

```
var action = {

  type:'YOUR_REQUEST',
  payload:{
    request:{
      ...yourRequestConfig
    },
    options:{
      onSuccess:()=>console.log('success)
    }
  }

}
```